# Python: How to pass more than one argument to the property getter?

Tags: python, properties, language-features

Consider the following example:

```
class A:
    @property
    def x(self): return 5
```

So, of course calling the `a = A(); a.x` will return `5`

But imagine that you want to be able to modify the property x.
This way, for example:

```
class A:
    @property
    def x(self, neg = False): return 5 if not neg else -5
```

And call it with `a = A(); a.x(neg=True)`

That will raise a TypeError: `'int' object is not callable`, that is quite normal, since our `x` is evaluated as `5`.

So, I would like to know how one can pass more then one argument to the property getter, if it is possible at all.

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Note that you don't *have* to use `property` as a decorator. You can quite happily use it the old way and expose the individual methods in addition to the property:

```
class A:
    def get_x(self, neg=False):
        return -5 if neg else 5
    x = property(get_x)

>>> a = A()
>>> a.x
5
>>> a.get_x()
5
>>> a.get_x(True)
-5
```

This may or may not be a good idea depending on exactly what you're doing with it (but I'd expect to see an excellent justification in a comment if I came across this pattern in any code I was reviewing)

Comment: Man... that is actually a brilliant idea. Wish more APIs used this instead of only setters-getters / only properties.

Comment: More decorators? They all support being used this way, as the decorator syntax is just sugar for a function call and name rebinding.

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean - more APIs exposing both the setter/getter methods *and* the related property.

Comment: BTW, if you use the property decorator, in theory you are not even allowed to have arguments. Failing in that you will be getting errors like <...> object is not callable

Comment: The idea of encapsulation is absent here. There is no point in using getters in this way. The interface is broken there.

Comment: I would use instead of `x = property(get_x)`, `@property def x(self): return self.get_x()`. More readable.

Comment: I needed to use this pattern to be able to pass `**kwargs` to the underlying function during unit testing, but still maintain the existing property API for the getter.

Answer (score 60):

I think you did not fully understand the purpose of properties.

If you create a property `x`, you'll accessing it using `obj.x` instead of `obj.x()`.
After creating the property it's not easily possible to call the underlying function directly.

If you want to pass arguments, name your method `get_x` and do not make it a property:

```
def get_x(self, neg=False):
    return 5 if not neg else -5
```

If you want to create a setter, do it like this:

```
class A:
    @property
    def x(self): return 5

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value): self._x = value
```

Comment: I know! And you can see the `a.x` call in my first example.

Comment: @Rizo: properties are just not designed for that.

Answer (score 22):

a property should only depend on the related object. If you want to use some external parameters, you should use methods.

Comment: Suppose you use a want to access  a property after some password validation how  will that be without passing that password to a getter.

Comment: @pentanol I'd argue that a property method is not the place for authentication code of an API.

Answer (score 11):

In your second example, you're using `a.x()` as if it were a function: `a.x(neg=True)`. With this in mind, why not just define it as a function?

Comment: That's a direct solution, but i'm using very complex getters and setters and would like to keep using them without having to write separate functions for the attributes.

Comment: This does not answer my question. I now I can use functions in python! :) I just want to know if there some way to force a property to act as a function.

Comment: @Rizo why? If you want it to act like a function, then use a function (method). But in answer to your question, the only way would be to return a callable from the property that takes parameter. Then you would have something that looks exactly like a function but less efficient.

Comment: If a getter does anything but returning a simple value (or a default value) it's not a "getter" anymore but a regular function.

Comment: @Rizo: in the example you are giving, it is probably wiser to just let the *caller* decide what to do with the return value. after all it is the *caller* passing in the condition.

Answer (score 9):

I know this question is old, but, for reference, you can call your property with an argument like that:

```
a = A()
assert a.x == 5
assert A.x.fget(a, True) == -5
```

As mentioned by others, this is not advised.

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, you could define two properties, which call an underlying function:

```
class A:
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x(neg = False)

    @property
    def x_neg(self):
        return self._x(neg = True)

    def _x(self, neg):
        return 5 if not neg else -5
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue. I have class Polynomial() and I'm defining a gradient that I would like to return a function if no arguments or evaluate if there are arguments. I want to store the gradient as an attribute so I don't need to calculate it every time I need to use it, and I want to use @property so the gradient attribute is calculated lazily. My solution was to define a class Gradient with a defined call method for Polynomial's grad property to return.

```
@property
def grad(self):
    """
    returns gradient vector
    """
    class Gradient(list):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            res = []
            for partial_derivative in g:
                res.append(partial_derivative(*args, **kwargs))
            return res
    g = Gradient()
    for i in range(1, len(self.term_matrix[0])):
        g.append(self.derivative(self.term_matrix[0][i]))
    return g
```

And then I have the following tests pass successfully:

```
def test_gradient(self):
    f = Polynomial('x^2y + y^3 + xy^3')
    self.assertEqual(f.grad, [Polynomial('2xy + y^3'), Polynomial('x^2 + 3xy^2 + 3y^2')])
    self.assertEqual(f.grad(x=1, y=2), [12, 25])
    f = Polynomial('x^2')
    self.assertEqual(f.grad(1), [2])
```

So, for this issue we could try:

```
class A:
    @property
    def x(self):
        class ReturnClass(int):
            def __call__(self, neg=False):
                if not neg:
                    return 5
                return -5
        return ReturnClass()
```

Comment: Not sure that the solution is working: If I say `a = A(); print(a.x)` I get 0 as a result - the default value of an non-initialized int. The solution - as far as understand - should be `5` for `a.x`.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to choose appropriate action based on variable with limited distinct values (cause you have limited distinct choices). Basically you may implement this by a tuple or dictionary, but you may implement it by inner class that defines allowed types.

For example we may generate specifically formatted data based on different sources, to further processing:

from formatted_data import FormattedData

class DataGenerator:

```
class TYPE:
    CSVFILE = 0
    SQLITE  = 1
    HTTP    = 2

@classmethod
def produceData(c, source_type: int, source_address) -> FormattedData:
    match source_type:
        case c.TYPE.CSVFILE:
            pass
        case c.TYPE.SQLITE:
            pass
        case c.TYPE.HTTP:
            pass
```

To call such classmethod:

```
DataGenerator.produceData(DataGenerator.TYPE.CSVFILE, '/financial_history.csv')
DataGenerator.produceData(DataGenerator.TYPE.SQLITE, '/financial_history.sqlite')
```