# Trying to create object property from function

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, properties

I am trying to create object properties from a function, like this:

```
class A:
    def get_x(self, neg=False):
        if neg:
            return -5
        else:
            return 5

    x = property(get_x)
    neg_x = property(get_x(neg=True))
```

I have tried following the advice from a [previous Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715620/python-how-to-pass-more-than-one-argument-to-the-property-getter), but with an added property `neg_x` I get this confusing error message:

```
TypeError: get_x() takes at least 1 argument (1 given)
```

Comment: What are you trying to do with `neg_x` , are you trying to create property??

Comment: I think it needs to be `neg_x = self.get_x(neg=True)`

Comment: that doesn't work, it says `name 'self' is not defined`

Comment: You need to add to you question example how you are trying to use the property. should be like A().neg_x or A().x

Answer (score 3):

When you try to assign:

```
neg_x = property(get_x(neg=True))
```

you are actually *calling* `get_x`, without the instance for `self`, and trying to pass the result (which would be `-5`, and therefore not a getter) to `property`. A much neater way to do this is:

```
class A:

    @property
    def x(self):
        return 5

    @property
    def neg_x(self):
        return -self.x
```

If you really want to use the function, you could use e.g. `lambda` (or `functools.partial`) to call the function when the property is accessed, rather than when defining it:

```
class A:

    def get_x(self, neg=False):
        if neg:
            return -5
        else:
            return 5

    x = property(get_x)

    neg_x = property(lambda self: self.get_x(neg=True))
```

In use:

```
>>> a = A()
>>> a.x
5
>>> a.neg_x
-5
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you: just pass value. of your neg. Check the last line.

```
class A:
    def get_x(self, neg=False):
        if neg:
            return -5
        else:
            return 5

    x = property(get_x)
    neg_x = property(get_x(True))
```