# TypeError: __init_subclass__() takes no keyword arguments related to subclass and abstract class design

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, abc

I implemented the following design using abstract class and its subclass class as follows

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Pipeline(ABC):  

    @abstractmethod
    def read_data(self):
        pass
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):        
        self.raw_data = self.read_data()        
        self.process_data = self.raw_data[self.used_cols]

   
class case1(Pipeline):
    def read_data(self):
        return pd.read_csv("file location") # just hard coding for the file location
       
    @property
    def used_cols(self):
        return ['col_1', 'col_2','col_3','col_4']
```

I can invoke the class of `case1` as follows. It will in fact read a csv file into pandas dataframe.

```
data = case1()
```

This existing design will return four hard coded columns, e.g., 'col_1','col_2','col_3' and 'col_4', and it just works fine. At present, I would like to control the columns to be returned by modifying the subclass, in specific, the function of `used_cols`. I modified class `case1` as follows, but it will cause the error message.

```
class case1(Pipeline):
    def read_data(self):
        return pd.read_csv("file location") # just hard coding for the file location

   
    @property
    def used_cols(self, selected_cols):
        return selectd_cols
```

It was called as follows

```
selected_cols = ['col_2','col_3']
data = case1(selected_cols)
```

It turns out that this modification is not right, and generates the error message such as
TypeError: **init_subclass**() takes no keyword arguments     So my question is how to modify the subclass to get the desired control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### reference

- [Python: How to pass more than one argument to the property getter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715620/python-how-to-pass-more-than-one-argument-to-the-property-getter)

> I think you did not fully understand the purpose of properties.

> If you create a property used_cols, you'll accessing it using obj.used_cols instead of obj.used_cols(). After creating the property it's not easily possible to call the underlying function directly.

#### csv file:

```
col_0,col_1,col_2,col_3
1,1,1,2
2,3,3,4
3,3,3,6
```

#### code:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import pandas as pd
class Pipeline(ABC):  

    @abstractmethod
    def read_data(self):
        pass
    
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):     
        self.raw_data = self.read_data()
        self.used_cols = kwargs["selected_cols"]
        self.process_data = self.raw_data[self.used_cols]

class case1(Pipeline):
    def read_data(self):
        return pd.read_csv("file_location.csv") # just hard coding for the file location

    @property
    def used_cols(self):
        return self._used_cols

    @used_cols.setter
    def used_cols(self,selected_cols):
        self._used_cols = selected_cols

selected_cols = ['col_2','col_3']
data = case1(selected_cols = selected_cols)
print(data.process_data)
```

#### result:

```
   col_2  col_3
0      1      2
1      3      4
2      3      6
```