# Override a property with super()

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, properties, overriding

I would like to override this parent property to make it conditional with a flag:

```
@property
def velocity(self):
    """Instantaneous velocity in km/h."""
    if self.time is not None:
        dt = np.diff(self.seconds)
        dd = np.diff(self.distance)
        vs = 3600 * dd / dt
        return self._resample(vs, self.seconds)
    else:
        return None
```

I can do this easily with something like this in the child:

```
@property
def velocity(self, flag=True):
    if flag:
        if self.time is not None:
            dt = np.diff(self.seconds)
            dd = np.diff(self.distance)
            vs = 3600 * dd / dt
            return self._resample(vs, self.seconds)
        else:
            return None
```

But shouldn't I be also able to do just this instead of copying the code vebatim? If I do that the "supered" function always returns None, no matter the flag or that self.time has not changed (and is not None):

```
@property
def velocity(self, flag=True):
    if flag:
        super().velocity
```

Comment: properties should not expect additional arguments... how would you pass that argument when calling the property?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5715620/python-how-to-pass-more-than-one-argument-to-the-property-getter

Comment: but why decorate `def velocity(self, flag=True):` with `@property`? how do you call that method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `return super().velocity`

```
@property
def velocity(self, flag=True):
    if flag:
        return super().velocity
```

Answer (score 0):

the point of using `@decorator` is that you can call the method as `obj.velocity`. no parentheses, no arguments. now as `obj.velocity` returns something (a dataframe?) `obj.velocity(False)` will try to **call** that dataframe with the argument `False`. this will fail..

you could make `flag` a class variable:

```
class SomeClass:
    FLAG = False

    @property
    def velocity(self):
        if SomeClass.FLAG:
            return super().velocity
```

and as already stated: you need to `return` the value in your method.

Comment: you could always just drop the `@property` decorator. not sure if that makes your linter any happier...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Thanks for pointing `@property`, my bad :D